# Route (or re-direct) top-level domain to subdirectory of rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, .htaccess, ruby-on-rails-4, rails-routing

I have a rails app which currently mounts one of several engines based on constraints which look at the current subdomain. What I'd like to also include is a constraint which looks at the current *top-level domain* and then mounts one of those engines at a particular subdirectory; e.g. `www.example.com` points to `subdirectory.railsapp.com/example`.

Here is my current `routes.rb`:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  mount Accounts::Engine, at: "/"

  constraints subdomain: "campaigns" do
    mount Petitions::Engine, at: "/"
  end

  constraints subdomain: "blog" do
    mount Blog::Engine, at: "/"
  end

  constraints subdomain: "events" do
    mount Calendar::Engine, at: "/"
  end

end
```

I would like add a condition where, if the domain is `www.example.com`, do something like `mount Petitions::Engine, at: "/example"`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a lambda/proc to implement an advanced constraint (http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#advanced-constraints):

```
get '/example', to: 'controller#action',
    constraints: lambda { |request| request.host.match /example/ }
```

That `request` is the same as the one you get in the controllers. You can check `request.env`, `request.remote_ip` and so on.

More docs: http://apidock.com/rails/v3.2.1/ActionDispatch/Routing/Mapper/Scoping/constraints

#### For your case you could do:

```
constraints(lambda { |request| request.host.match /example/ }) do
  mount Petitions::Engine, at: "/example"
end
```